# Least squares approximation problem of $t^3$ in a subspace spanned by even degree polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I am having trouble solving the following question,

Let $P_9 ([-1,1])$ be the complex vector space consisting of polynomials $p:[-1,1] \rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with degree 9 or lower. With the inner product

$$\langle f,g\rangle =  \int_{-1}^1 \! f(t)\overline{g(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t$$

Let $W$ be the subspace of $P_9$ spanned by the polynomials of even degree.
So $W$ is the span of $\{1,t^2,t^4,t^6,t^8\}$.

a) Determine the best approximation in $W$ of the polynomial $t^3$.

I assumed it had to be a least squares approximation problem and so I tried and horribly failed at making a matrix $A$ to use $A^tAx=A^tb$ where $x$ and $b$ are vectors. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: One wonders what was done of the indication in the accepted answer below since, either following it faithfully and arriving at a Cramer system of size 5x5 and solving rather painfully this system, or bypassing these computations completely and using a simple *convexity* observation, one arrives at the fact that the best polynomial approximation of $t^3$ in the space $W$ of even polynomials is $$\color{red}{\bf 0}.$$ Which makes the accepted answer even more incomplete, so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to minimize

> $$f(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) = \int_{-1}^{1} \left(t^3-\sum_{i=0}^{4}a_i t^{2i}\right)^2 dt $$

which can be done by differentiating with respect to $a_i, i=0,\ldots,4$ and equating to $0$ and solving the resulted system in $a_i$

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Thank you for the edit!